# Multiple Calls from SignalR client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

on my asp.net mvc application i'm using signalR to notify db changes to application. my problem is once i page reloaded. signalR client get called multiple time.

i used `SqlDependency` for get sql db changes my code as below

```
public List<Load> GetAllReportSignalR()
{
    var loads = new List<Load>();
    var connectionString = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT LoadId, [FileName], LoadTypeId, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, LoadStatusId FROM [dbo].[Load]", connection))
        {
            command.Notification = null;
            var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange +=new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                loads.Add(
                        new Load
                        {
                            FileName = (string)reader["FileName"],
                            CreatedBy = (string)reader["CreatedBy"],
                            CreatedDate = (DateTime)reader["CreatedDate"],
                            LoadId = (int)reader["LoadId"],
                            LoadStatusId = (int)reader["LoadStatusId"],
                            LoadTypeId = (short)reader["LoadTypeId"]
                        });
            }
        }

    }
    return loads;
}


private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        Notifier.UpdateDataTable();
    }

}
```

On my hub

```
[HubMethodName("updateDataTable")]
public void UpdateDataTable()
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Notifier>();
    context.Clients.All.updateData();
}
```

then i call signalR client

```
   var notifier = $.connection.notifier;
notifier.client.updateData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/LoadData',
        success: function (d) {
            reloadTbl(d)
        }
    });
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/LoadData',
        success: function (d) {
            reloadTbl(d)
        }
    });
}).fail(function(e) {

});
```

I started and stopped `SqlDependency` on `Application_Start()` and `Application_End()`

i did follow below example and that has the same problem ([CodeProject Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M))

Comment: I think we need a bit more code to work out why it's being called twice.  IE most of the Javascript code

Comment: hi i updated code with complete code. and on client side those are the code i'm using

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I just looked at the code on that page and it is the same as yours.

Comment: I Updated. Only commented section do call the function which `LoadData` withing that function call the `GetAllReportSignalR` and get the data re-register `SqlDependency  OnChange` Event

Comment: Please specify exactly (steps to reproduce) what _signalR client get called multiple time_ means. I suppose you know that everything in `.done()` is called on _every page refresh_, righ?

Comment: yeah. i was debugging came up problem with registering OnChange Event `SqlDependency` OnChange event fires multiple times. and one more thing for the application i'm using entity framework. i suspect that whether entity framework do some changes on database and trigger the `OnChange` Event

Comment: is there any way to release on OnChange Events (on `SqlDependency ` class) on page reload

Comment: can you go through this tutorial i did exactly same as it says. but this sample also getting same problem. as i said. this will help you to reproduce  .
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M

Answer (score -1):

When your page is loaded you did

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/LoadData',
        success: function (d) {
            reloadTbl(d)
        }
    });
})
```

which called back to the server to load data.

In addition, you had

```
var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange +=new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        Notifier.UpdateDataTable();
    }

}
```

which registered to data changed. For the callback above, it would trigger **dependency_OnChange**, which then called back to the client side.

Therefore, your page was refreshed twice. One was from server pushed, and the other from client pulled.

**Solution:**
 You may choose to push from server to client when the page is loaded and remove the client pulls code.

Comment: Hi Toan i removed ajax call from signalR hub start done and on page load called separately but problem still there getting multiple calls

Comment: Hi Gayan, I suggest you put a breakpoint inside UpdateDataTable() method and look at stacktrace, then you will discover why there are multiple calls to clients.

Comment: i did. but have no idea how to fix it could you please post some code samples please?

Comment: So can you add back the ajax call on startup and remove the dependency call from server side. I don't have your program, so I cannot tell where it is wrong. If you can look at the call stack from server, you should know why it was called multiple times.